# Django templates: use variable in block tag

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

What I want is to set a variable once and use it twice in two different block tags. This is the way I did it:

`something.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    
{% with title="Hellville De Luxe" %}
    {% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
    {% block description %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

`base.html`:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}">
```

Didn't work and I wonder why. I thought Django would replace the variable with its value. If I replace `{{ title }}` with a string, just like this: `{% block title %}Hats are cool{% endblock %}` it gets rendered perfectly.

Am I missing something or is this really stupid and I should try something very differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The scope for you variable `title` is the block where has been declared

Comment: I wonder if you rename `{% block title %}` to something else, what is going to happen

Comment: If you extend a template. It doesn't render or process anything that is outside of a block. That's just how they work

Comment: @Sayse that answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is to define template tags. Go to your template tag directory create some py file lets say `define_variable_tag.py`;

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()
somevariable = "first_text"
@register.simple_tag
def define_variable(variable):
    global somevariable
    somevariable = variable
    return somevariable

@register.simple_tag
def get_variable():
    global somevariable
    return somevariable
```

And in your template,you should load your template tag `{% load define_variable_tag %}` in the beginning of the template and you can use them like this;

```
{% define_variable "something "%}
 <h3>Some Text</h3>
 {% get_variable %}
```

This `{% get_variable %}` will return you "something". You can use it everywhere in your template.

Answer (score 0):

The code outside of [{% block %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#block) doesn't affect the code inside of `{% block %}` because the code inside of `{% block %}` is evaluated first.

`{% block %}` is explained in [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) as shown below:

- Variables created outside of a {% block %} using the template tag as syntax can’t be used inside the block. For example, this template doesn’t render anything:

```
{% translate "Title" as title %}
{% block content %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
```

- {% block %} tags are evaluated first. That’s why the content of a block is always overridden, regardless of the truthiness of surrounding tags. For example, this template will always override the content of the title block:

```
{% if change_title %}
    {% block title %}Hello!{% endblock title %}
{% endif %}
```